# How to install Hazelcast IMDG in Ubuntu Server?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, hazelcast, devicehive

I need a guide how to install Hazelcast IMDG in Ubuntu Server.

I've already installed the components for DeviceHive framework:

- PostgreSQL 9.1 or above.
- Apache Kafka 0.10.0.0 or above.
- Oracle JDK 8 or OpenJDK 8.
- Maven.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can check out the following resources:

- [Hazelcast Reference Manual: Getting Started](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/#getting-started)
- [Hazelcast Reference Manual: Using the Scripts in the Package](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/#using-the-scripts-in-the-package)

---

In general if you already have your JRE installed, you need the **following steps**:

1. Download Hazelcast from https://hazelcast.org/imdg/download/
2. Unzip it
3. Start it with the `/bin/start.sh` script

---

Optionally, you can:

- Add your custom `hazelcast.xml` (`hazelcast.yaml`) configuration
- Add Hazelcast as a unix service